# Identify the error - Discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, fake-proofs

I'm having problems trying to identify the error in this proof in the question below:

Let $u$, $m$, $n$ be three integers. If $u\mid mn$ and $\gcd(u,m) = 1$, then $m = \pm1$.

1. If $\gcd(u,m) = 1$, then $1 = us + mt$ for some integers $s$, $t$.
2. If $u\mid mn$, then $us = mn$ for some integer $s$.
3. Hence, $1 = mn + mt = m(n + t)$, which implies that $m\mid1$, and therefore $m = \pm1$.

My thought is the error is between steps 2 and 3.  Inferring that $us = mn$ for some integer $s$ is correct.  But substituting into the formula is incorrect because we now have .. two different "$m$" integers in the final step.

I can easily find a counterexample, but I'm not sure if the reasoning for my identifying the error is correct.

Comment: What are you allegedly proving anyway?

Comment: The correct conclusion of statement (1.) is If $u|mn$ and $\gcd(u,m)=1,$ then $u|n$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks.  I am trying to find the problem with the proof.  And the assumption is Step 1.  I did not explain myself well.  I will re-edit to explain better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstof all your statement 1 is wrong.
Example- 5|2*25, gcd(5,2)=1, but 2 is not equal to 1 or -1.
Correct statement should be if u|mn, gcd(u,m)=1 then u|n.
And now the error in your proof is you have choosen same integer 's' in both step 2 and 3. 
1=us+mt 
then u|mn implies mn=ua for some integer a.

Comment: That was my thinking.  The integer in step 2 and 3 is repeated.  I don't know how to explain it well, but yes... that's a better way.  the integer is repeated.  Which results in being able to substitute us for mt in the final step (but the product of mt could be a different value for m)... ugh.. I'm horrible at explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Look at step 1 when $u=1$, $m=n=2$.